# SQL Server: profile name is not valid

Tags: sql-server

We have a mail profile that is in use by a number of users all of which are spread between 2 AD group logins (basic users & elevated users).  This mail profile works fine no issues and has done for 2+ years.

We had a new starter who got added to the basic users group but when she runs an SP using DBmail with this same mail profile she gets the 'profile name is not valid' error, however, the mail still gets sent.  Other users have been setup in the same way in the previous month with no issues.

Another user (same rights) runs the same SP and no errors are generated.  We moved her to the elevated rights group and it works with no errors, move her back and we get the error again.

I'm not sure what i can try next to stop this from happening, any suggestions are welcome, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Do any of the ideas here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491053/profile-name-is-not-valid -- help?

Comment: Thanks, i've looked at the article and but none of it applies.  The same mail profile is used by both my groups of users but only this new user is getting the error.  We tried switching her to the elevated users group and got her to run the same SP and no error is displayed, we then swapped her back to the original group which the majority of our users are members of and she gets the error again.